# The bucket does not allow ACLs in github action

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a static web-site stored in AWS S3 and delivered with Cloudfront. I want to deploy updates to the bucket with the following github action .yaml file
name: Upload to S3

```
on: [pull_request]

jobs:
  upload:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@main
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '12.x'
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build
      - uses: shallwefootball/s3-upload-action@master
        with:
          aws_key_id: ${{ secrets.AWS_KEY_ID }}
          aws_secret_access_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}}
          aws_bucket: ${{ secrets.AWS_BUCKET }}
          source_dir: 'dist'
```

I saw in another stack overflow question similiar to this that I need to enable ACL but i can not edit it and it has this message: This bucket has the bucket owner enforced setting applied for Object Ownership

Comment: If you cannot supply an ACL, then use AWS credentials associated with the AWS account that owns the S3 bucket or have the bucket owner enable [Bucket Owner Enforced](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/about-object-ownership.html).